# InAppBilling Issue

Tags: android, in-app-billing

When I implement InAppBilling, the Following screen appears.. I used this link

- http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment/

for implementing InAppBilling

so where am I wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you are using a version of the app that is signed with your debug key or you are trying to purchase using your developer account which is not allowed.

You should also have uploaded an apk to Play store that has the billing permissions (although you do not need to publish it)

You need to sign your apk with your release key. Trying to purchase in debug mode will not work.

See this link for full testing instructions.
http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

Comment: I don't know how to create APK with release key. I use "Use the Export Wizard" to export and sign an APK From Manifist File Of App in eclipse.

Comment: Additionally it takes sometime (up to two hours) for the draft app you  uploaded to be activated.

Answer (score 2):

May be you are running this app from eclipse directly.

Whenever you are using In-App purchase in your app.

Export **signed APK** then try out this...